# How to use apply functions on multiple raster stacks

Tags: r, loops, regression, apply, raster

*Dear R programmers,
I am trying to convert a loop into an apply type formulation when using a particular 
function called dissever. It is a downscaling function, and works with raster data.
it takes a coarse input rasterLayer and a stack of covariates and produces a model object
that includes the fine resolution version of the input rasterLayer
for example:*

```
library(dissever)
library(raster)

mod.fine = dissever(
    coarse = edgeroi$carbon,   # coarse resolution raster  
    fine = edgeroi$predictors, # stack of fine resolution covariates
    method = "lm", # regression method used
    p = 0.05, # proportion of pixels sampled for training regression model

  )
```

I want to use a stack of coarse inputs layers, instead of a single rasterLayer. I can do that using a loop to fit a model that uses the same stack of fine resolution predictors for each layer of the coarse stack, and I can store results in a list. E.g. :

```
#create the stack of coarse layers

Stack.coarse = stack(edgeroi$carbon,edgeroi$carbon*2)


test = list()

   for(i in 1:nlayers(Stack.coarse)) {
     tmp=dissever(coarse=Stack.coarse[[i]],fine=edgeroi$predictors,method="lm",p=0.05)
       test[[i]]=tmp
  }
```

But I would like to avoid loops and would like to use apply functions instead.
Stacks are a special type of list and can be converted to list if necessary using as.list(stack.name)

However, I can't' find the right syntax that allows me to use lapply or mapply instead of a loop because these functions seem to expect only one list, while there are 2 separate stacks (lists) in input.

Can anyone help please,
Sarah

Comment: Maybe `map2` or `pmap`? https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html & https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/foundations-of-functional-programming-with-purrr/more-complex-iterations?ex=10

Comment: Your description is not very clear. Is it true that you fit a model for each coarse grid cell, and that you then apply this model to all fine grid cells that fall into the coarse grid cell? (that would be a tricky, but interesting problem). Or do you fit one global model with the coarse data (in which case you can just use `predict` )

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mapply` to run a function that gets corresponding elements of equal-length lists. For example:

```
> one = list(1,2,3,4,5)
> two = list(4,3,4,3,4)
```

Then:

```
> mapply(function(aone, atwo){aone+atwo}, one,two)
[1] 5 5 7 7 9
```

If the output of your function is more complicated, you get a list of them back:

```
> mapply(function(aone, atwo){list(aone+atwo)}, one,two)
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 7

[[4]]
[1] 7

[[5]]
[1] 9
```

If your lists aren't equal-length then R will apply its usual recycling rules and complain if one list doesn't fit an integer number of times into the other.